# How to send form-encoded List<long> from SwaggerUI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger

I'm getting 400 Bad Request on sending `List<long>` from SwaggerUI to .net application

**Swagger**
[image]

**Response** : {"statusCode":400,"message":["The value '"1","2","3"' is not valid."]}

**Payload**

[image]

**Modal used by Swagger**

```
public class DataArgs {
   public List<string> strVar { get; set; }
   public List<long> longVar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: View source please, not this cooked version

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your swagger config as it is passing the integer values as strings. The quotes should not be there.